# What's wrong with this query? Doubling quotes error

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error

> ERROR: Syntax error at or near "''"

I searched about putting single quotes and this way seemed to be correct, doubling quotes, but it's not working

```
SELECT 
    cod_rede_credenciada_produto,
    rep.des_cnpj_loja,
    emf.des_header_estabelecimento,
    TRIM(COALESCE (cep.uf_logradouro, '''')),
    TRIM(COALESCE(cep.cidade_logradouro, '''')),
    TRIM(COALESCE (cep.bairro_ini_logradouro, emf.complresidencia)),
    TRIM(COALESCE (cep.desc_tipo_logradouro, '''') || '' '' || COALESCE (cep.titulo_logradouro, '''') || '' '' || COALESCE (cep.nome_logradouro, emf.ruaresidencia) || '', '' || COALESCE (emf.numresidencia, '''')),
    pro.des_produto,
    des_cnpj_loja
FROM 
    solucoes.slereprede_credenciada_produto rep
INNER JOIN 
    solucoes.sleproproduto pro ON rep.cod_produto = pro.cod_produto
LEFT JOIN 
    empresafilha emf ON emf.cgc = rep.des_cnpj_loja
LEFT JOIN 
    caecep_cep cep ON cep.cep_logradouro = emf.cepresidencia
```

Comment: unrelated, but: `concat_ws(' ', ...)` will make things a lot easier if you want to concat multiple columns with a delimiter and treat empty/null values properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one problem:

```
|| '' '' ||
```

If you want a space:

```
|| ' ' ||
```

If you want single quotes with a space between them:

```
|| ''' ''' ||
```

Comment: If you think this is the best solution to your problem. Then you should accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark beside it to toggle it from greyed out to fill in. @Samuel Almeida